# Using alsa mixer (root) to boost sound in an intelligent way

Tags: volume

I'm looking for a way to boost the headphone output of my Moto X (2013). I have rooted it and installed [Alsa Mixer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skvalex.alsamixer&hl=en) so I should be able to run shell scripts and modify it.

The thing is.. I can't find any good guides for this.

What I'm trying to do:
- Boost the volume using a compressor (like radio stations tend to do)
- Maybe apply a limiter after that just to be sure I don't blow up my headphones.

Can somebody help me plz?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Have you already tried our powerful search feature, and checked e.g. for [volume boost](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=volume+boost+answers%3A1)? Was your solution amongst the results? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to install Viper4Android. You can increase output by (as I recall) 8dB, and besides that, you will get a lot of options to adapt the sound to get the best output. Using it for a couple of years and still haven't found a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks I stumbled upon this myself yesterday but wanted to try it for a littke before answering my own question. It's a bit of a hassle to get it working (softbricked my phone because I forgot to restore build.prop file permissions) but once it works it *really* works!

Comment: In settings, set the UI mode to Expert, you will get all the options available. If you stay in default mode much of the options (including the output dB strength) are hidden.